# Handling two UITextFields and delegates

Tags: objective-c

Hi I was taking care of one UITextField easily. e.g., Set delegate of UITextField my view controller and implement such method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    // Removes the keyboard from the screen
    [self.textFieldProperty1 resignFirstResponder];


    return YES;
}
```

But what if I have two UITextFields? A delegate for both of them will still be my view controller. And how do I implement the above method then? Like this?

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {

        // Removes the keyboard from the screen
        [self.textFieldProperty1 resignFirstResponder];
        [self.textFieldProperty2 resignFirstResponder];


        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, this is how you do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your method as you pass the delegate to your property it will automatically identify from which textField method is called:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    // Removes the keyboard from the screen
    [textField resignFirstResponder];


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag for more specific to each textfield deleget methods :

```
if (textField.tag == 1) {
        UITextField *passwordTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
        [passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Please review this refrence get more idea. 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate/

Answer (score 1):

As far as it is just about resigning the first responder, this would do:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

In the event that you want to add some more post processing:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (textField == self.textFieldProperty1) {
        //process property 1 here
    } else {
        // process property 2 here 
    }
}
```

In the event that you do not hold a property or any other suitable reference to the `UITextField` (or whicheveer) objects then you can use the `UIView` `tag` property to identify them and distinguish beteen them.